# Accessing JSON string created in jsp from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

in jsp scriptlet I assign a value to string variable that matches json syntax.

```
<%

  String jsonString = "{jsonsyntax}";
%>
```

In javscript I access it like:

```
var json= <%=jsonString %>;
```

The problem with this, when, in browser I use "view page source" I see the content of variable. 
how can I avoid it?

or Maybe it is possible to move it to external js file?

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSP scriptlet is setting the JSON as string to your page you get to see its content.

If you want to avoid that you need to pass to the JavaScript code the JSON as an Object.

You can use an AJAX call for retrieving the JSON and then you can get it as an object.

Comment: can I avoid use of ajax?

Comment: @yuris: Of course, if you do what you are doing now. But then the data is contained in the page source. It's either one or the other.

Comment: So my javascript must initiate the ajax request  and in jsp I must catch it and return as attribute? Can you show an example?